# Wrapping C++ void functions with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ class containing void functions which take STL vectors passed by reference and modify the contents of one of those vectors. For example:

`void somefunction(std::vector<double> &result, std::vector<double> &array1, std::vector<double> &array2) {some calculations}`

And the pybind11 binding looks like this:

`.def("somefunction", &somefunction)`

I have included the 'pybind11/stl.h' header file which handles the automatic conversion between STL containers and python equivalents and in Python I call `somefunction` with Python lists but I'm not sure if the C++ layer can modify the `result` Python list.

My then question is how to write Python
bindings for C++ functions which modify the contents of an STL vector passed by reference and return `void`.

Answer (score 2):

Including `pybind11/stl.h` results to copy-conversions between c++ and pyhton, see http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#automatic-conversion

To pass by reference see section http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types

Comment: So if I understood the docs correctly, I should make use of the `PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE()` macro and a corresponding `class_` declaration? What do I then pass to  `somefunction` in Python?

Comment: You should pass a python counterpart of your `std::vector<int>`, the `VectorOfInt`. Something like `a = VectorOfInt([1,2]); b = VectorOfInt([1,2]); somefunction(a, b)` I believe.